# aws appsync graphql api with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I want to access AWS AppSync API using Python code and confused with requests library.

Auth mode is Cognito user pool. My questions are:

1. How to get access tokens from Cognito user pool?
2. How to make queries, mutations, and handle subscriptions?

I tried to do it with auth mode API key. but I am getting the following error.

```py
import requests
import json

URL = "https://vtcarmq7zzeadnkwzcgfr24irm.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql"

headers = {"x-api-key":"da2-bwuyzqchhfgyxemcmdinjegb7e"}

data = json.dumps({
    "query": '''
    
  listTodos(filter:{
    title:{
      contains:"g"
    }     
  }   )     {
    items{
      id title duedate     
    }   
  }
'''

} )

r = requests.request("POST", URL , data = data , headers = headers)

print(r.text)
```

> {   "errors" : [ {
> "message" : "Unable to parse GraphQL query.",
> "errorType" : "MalformedHttpRequestException"   } ] }

I have seen this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2U4RsbFO4bA&t=1172s
In this video, for authentication using cognito user pool, he says to make a call to cognito user pool and get the tokens and pass it to aws appsync in headers.

I am new to aws and python request module, trying to write python code for this video.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to show us what you've already attempted before, where you've looked, and potentially some code you've written.

Comment: I have made changes in the question and added the code  which  I tried  to run .

Answer (score -1):

[graphql-python/gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql) supports AWS AppSync since [version 3.0.0rc0](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql/releases/tag/v3.0.0rc0).

It supports queries, mutation and even subscriptions on the realtime endpoint.

It supports IAM, api key and JWT authentication methods.

The documentation is available [here](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transports/appsync.html)

Here is an example of a mutation using the API Key authentication:

```py
import asyncio
import os
import sys
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from gql import Client, gql
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport
from gql.transport.appsync_auth import AppSyncApiKeyAuthentication

# Uncomment the following lines to enable debug output
# import logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


async def main():

    # Should look like:
    # https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appsync-api.REGION.amazonaws.com/graphql
    url = os.environ.get("AWS_GRAPHQL_API_ENDPOINT")
    api_key = os.environ.get("AWS_GRAPHQL_API_KEY")

    if url is None or api_key is None:
        print("Missing environment variables")
        sys.exit()

    # Extract host from url
    host = str(urlparse(url).netloc)

    auth = AppSyncApiKeyAuthentication(host=host, api_key=api_key)

    transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url=url, auth=auth)

    async with Client(
        transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=False,
    ) as session:

        query = gql(
            """
mutation createMessage($message: String!) {
  createMessage(input: {message: $message}) {
    id
    message
    createdAt
  }
}"""
        )

        variable_values = {"message": "Hello world!"}

        result = await session.execute(query, variable_values=variable_values)
        print(result)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380599/appsync-function-with-opensearch can you help me here too